# Change FileServlet root path

Tags: java, servlets, resin

I use Resin webserevr. 
There is great FileServlet class for serving static content. 
I'd like to remap URIs like

```
/user1/file.txt -> /users/dir1/1/file.txt
/user2/file.txt -> /users/dir2/22/file.txt
...
```

in runtime.

But username->path mapping is not static and based on some database data.

Answer (score 0):

You would map your /user URLs to a servlet, which would in turn **forward** the request to Resin's FileServlet

```
   final String actualFilePath = dao.getFilePathFor("/user1/file.txt");
   final RequestDispatcher disp = request.getRequestDispatcher("/mystaticmapping" + actualFilePath);
   disp.include(request, response);
```